# js passing this to onclick function throught listenner

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, this, listener

I linked a function to *onclick* event inside a listener but I can't access constructor context to call its argument **events**

```
export class VueMapComponent {
constructor(public geolocation: Geolocation, public events: Events) {}

google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', () => { 
        let element = document.getElementById('flash');
        element.onclick = this.funct_flasher;
    });

funct_flasher() {
    console.log("funct_flasher", "funct_flasher called");
    //this.events.publish('flash_sended'); // Problem can't access 
}}
```

Can you explain to me what's wrong, please ?

Comment: If that is the formatting of your code, there might already be some issues caused by syntax. Is that supposed to be you constructor body?

Comment: it's just an ionic component class of angular ionic project, strange like you can think it works like that.